# Rails: Why does find(id) raise an exception in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Model.find(1) gives ActiveRecord error when id 1 does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966430/model-find1-gives-activerecord-error-when-id-1-does-not-exist)

If there is no user with an id of 1 in the database, trying `User.find(1)` will raise an exception.

Why is this?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Because that's the way the architects intended find(id) to work, as indicated in the RDoc:

> Find by id - This can either be a specific id (1), a list of ids (1, 5, 6), or an array of ids ([5, 6, 10]). If no record can be found for all of the listed ids, then RecordNotFound will be raised.

If you don't want the exception to be raised, use find_by_id, which will return nil if it can't find an object with the specified id.  Your example would then be `User.find_by_id(1)`.

Comment: But what's the advantage of it returning RecordNotFound? Why would someone want this behaviour instead of just returning nil?

Comment: RecordNotFound is raised, not returned.  This allows the caller's control flow to be different, because you don't have to check the return value being nil (you'd use a begin/rescue block instead).

Comment: That still doesn't explain why it's the default behaviour where in most all other parts of ActiveRecord, the default behaviour is to return nil or false for failures, and leave the exception control flow to methods ending in a bang (#save!).

Comment: I think the reason for raising the error is so the base controller can catch it and show show the 404 page.  If you hit /widgets/2 and there is no widget with id==2, then you get a 404, which IMO makes sense.

Comment: `find_by_id` is deprecated in Rails 4 :( https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders

Comment: @TobiasCohen That's not true. From the link you posted: "Note that `find(primary_key)`, `find_by...`, and `find_by...!` are not deprecated."

Comment: @Nick `find_by_id(1)` is deprecated indeed. But you could use `find_by(id: 1)`.

Comment: @Faith Yup, you're absolutely right. Must have read it wrong at the time.

Comment: What if there is an error saying that `find_by_id` doesn't exist?

Comment: The explanation of how to avoid the exception is useful, but nothing here actually answers the question of why it is the way it is. In other words, "because the people who made it wanted it that way" is not a useful answer, and neither is "the documentation says it is that way".

Answer (score -8):

Further to runako's explanation, it's actually pretty useful to have the choice of whether an exception is raised or not. I'm working on a blog application and I wanted to add support for viewing the next or previous blog entry. I was able to add two instance methods to my `Post` model that simply return `nil` when you try to get the previous post when viewing the first post, or the next post when viewing the last post:

```
def next
  Post.find_by_id(id + 1)
end

def previous
  Post.find_by_id(id - 1)
end
```

This avoids my helper code which conditionally generates the Previous Post/Next Post links from having to handle the `RecordNotFound` exception, which would be bad because it would be using an exception for control flow.

Comment: Wouldn't this be pretty fragile if your records in your DB didn't have sequential id's?

Comment: @zoltarSpeaks It would, but in practice they do have sequential IDs, so it's a total non-issue.

Comment: If, for example, you have a exclusion, you will get with a sporadic bug that is difficult to track. A better way to achieve the next/previous would be, something like: Post.where("id > ?", id).limit(1) for next and Post.where("id < ?", id).limit(1) to get the previous

Comment: And if a `Post` gets deleted from the db?

Comment: The described use case might be bad (see the other comments), but the essence "it's actually pretty useful to have the choice of whether an exception is raised or not" is totally correct, IMHO!