# Rails 2: Model.find(1) gives ActiveRecord error when id 1 does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using Rails 2.3.5 and in that if I give `Model.find(1)` and if 1 is not in the database, it returns ActiveRecord error. Should it just be returning `nil` as in the case of `Model.find_by_column('..')`?

Comment: For a rails 4 answer please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26885027/645223

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. I think David explains this the best himself, so here is a quote from Ruby, S., Thomas, D. & Hansson, D.H., 2009. [*Agile Web Development with Rails*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356166), Third Edition Third Edition., Pragmatic Bookshelf (p.330).

> When you use a finder driven by
>   primary keys, you’re looking for a
>   particular record. You expect it to
>   exist. A call to Person.find(5) is
>   based on our knowledge of the people
>   table. We want the row with an id of
>   5. If this call is unsuccessful—if the record with the id of 5 has been
>   destroyed—we’re in an exceptional
>   situation. This mandates the raising
>   of an exception, so Rails raises
>   RecordNotFound.
>
> On the other hand,
>   finders that use criteria to search
>   are looking for a match. So,
>   Person.find(:first,
>   :conditions=>"name=’Dave’") is the
>   equivalent of telling the database (as
>   a black box) “Give me the first person
>   row that has the name Dave.” This
>   exhibits a distinctly different
>   approach to retrieval; we’re not certain up front that we’ll get a result.
>   It’s entirely possible the result set
>   may be empty. Thus, returning nil in
>   the case of finders that search for
>   one row and an empty array for finders
>   that search for many rows is the
>   natural, nonexceptional response.

Comment: If you want the exception to be thrown in find_by_attributes flavors of the finder methods, you can use the bang! version of the method.

For example,

    Model.find_by_category!(a_category_value)

will throw RecordNotFound if no match is found.

I found this to be DRY in scenarios like RESTful controllers, where I have a common error handler for the exception and I want my actions to behave consistently when a resource matching the given parameters is not found.

Comment: The confusion about this is repeated with everyone coming to Rails, and getting an exception. The confusion / surprise is because `find` is a soft verb, and doesn't explicitly state precision or foreknowledge of existence. Of course, we're saddled with the decision now, but it's a question that will be asked as long as new people start to use Rails.

Answer (score 25):

If you really don't want the exception, you can use `find_by_id`:

```
# @user = User.find(params[:id])    # original code
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
if @user
    # found!
else
    # not found
end
```

This should be faster than a separate `exists?` check.

EDIT: Note that as @Miguelgraz commented, in Rails 4 you should instead say `User.find_by(id: params[:id])`. Same functionality, but now the implementation won't need `method_missing`.

Comment: This is deprecated in rails 4, please see this other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26885027/645223

Answer (score 7):

throwing the exception is the expected behavior.

in fact in the normal course of events if you let the exception go unhandled your rails server will return the proper 404 page not found error.

if you'd like for it to return nil you can catch it yourself:

```
begin
  @model = Model.find(id_provided)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  @model = nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks..I also found the error and I found it annoying..We can use `Model.find_by_id(1)` but I find it clumsy.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the exception to be thrown in find_by_attributes flavors of the finder methods, you can use the bang! version of the method.

For example,

```
Model.find_by_category!(a_category_value)
```

will throw RecordNotFound if no match is found.

I found this to be DRY in scenarios like RESTful controllers, where I have a common error handler for the exception and I want my actions to behave consistently when a resource matching the given parameters is not found.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the record exists before fetching it.

```
@model = Model.find(id) if Model.exists?(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Rails 4 Method**

```
if user = User.find_by(id: params[:id]) 
  #do something with user
else
  #throw error or redirect
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **find_by** with the required attribute (in your case the id) this will return nil instead of giving an error if the given id is not found.

```
Model.find_by_id(id_value)
```

You could also use **where** but you have to know that where return an active record relation with zero or more records you need to use first to return only one record or nil in case zero records return.

```
Model.where(id: id_value).first
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
user = User.find(10) rescue nil
```

Comment: [You should not use inline rescue.](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/don-t-inline-rescue-in-ruby). Rather use `begin...rescue RecordNotFound...end`