# How to handle active record find params[:id] in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wondering what is best practive for handling this type of situation in ruby on rails.

users_controller.rb

```
def show
  @user = User.find params[:id]
end
```

If user is not found it throws an exception which isn't catched anywhere so it will display some ugly things to enduser.

Solution would be pack it into begin...rescue...end block:

```
def show
  begin
    @user = User.find params[:id]
  rescue
    flash[:error] = "User not found"
    redirect :action => :index
  end
end
```

although I've never seen such code in any rails article or tutorial I've seen.

What is the proper way of handling this type of situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your requirement.
But you want a general solution then you can have a rescue block in `ApplicaionController` which will handle the `RecordNotFound` exception.

Comment: thanks, defing rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ApplicationController will do the trick :)

Answer (score 3):

See docs [rescue_from](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from)

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  unless @user
    flash[:error] = "User not found"
    redirect :action => :index
  end
end
```

But you cant expect you will call a link with id which is not in the db from within the application. Please see the answer of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966430/model-find1-gives-activerecord-error-when-id-1-does-not-exist)

Comment: thank's for the link, but I think I can expect wrong id because input comes from user and he can mess with url and I want some friendly message telling that what he was looking for doesn't exisit.

Answer (score 1):

The development environment will show you ugly error messages, but a production environment will just give an HTTP 404 error (page not found) when the id is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may be able to fix this with
 `@user = User.find(params[:id] = current_user)`