# How can I skip an error if find returns nothing in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a system where user can only see articles that he or she wrote.

In Articles controller, I put below line

```
@article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
```

where params[:id] is an article_id.

I just want to know how I can skip the error from displaying and just redirect to the :index action if article does not exist, or if user does not have permission to view it. 
I put @article.nil? conditional statement after above find statement, but it seems that the find statement above produces the error immediately like below.

Couldn't find Article with ID=1662 [WHERE (`articles`.user_id = 1)]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966430/model-find1-gives-activerecord-error-when-id-1-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

ActiveRecord::Base.find always throws an exception if it does not find a record, this is intentional.  You should only use `find` if you absolutely expect to have whatever it is you're looking for.  If you are rending a show action and can't find the article, you should rescue that exception and render a 404 (Not found) instead of redirecting to index (technically).

If you want to find something by it's `id` attribute without forcing an exception, use the dynamic finder `find_by_id` which will return false if it doesn't find a record with that id.

**Edit:**

Dynamic finders now have a different signature, `find_by_id` should now be:

`find_by :id, id_to_find`

See the new [Rails Guide on Querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object)

Comment: I would recommend using `find_by` instead

Comment: `find_by` didn't exist when this question was asked. I did add a link to the guide and dynamic finders section though.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `find_by_id` or any of the methods given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966430/model-find1-gives-activerecord-error-when-id-1-does-not-exist).

Answer (score 2):

The find() method raises a RecordNotFound exception, while methods such as find_by_id will return a nil value.  So you have a couple options you can wrap your method call in with a begin/rescue, add a rescue_from block to your controller:

```
rescue_from(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) {|e| do something here }
```

or use a find_by_id method and handle the condition where nil is returned.

There are actually a number of other alternatives, but the ones above are a good start, with find_by_id probably being the easiest.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the ActiveRecord find method raises an exception when it can't find a specific ID.  You can solve this a couple ways, the best way seems to be

```
begin
  @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
rescue
  redirect_to articles_path
end
```