# Rails Query for best way to select the most recent record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have this method which I want me to fetch the most recent `activity_id` for the corresponding `user_id` from the model `UserActivity` that keeps track of all the user activities and from that get the `description` of the activity_id from another model `Activity`.
The function works fine but at times throws bugs as "Not able to find activity_id". May be there could be a better way to implement this or Am I doing something wrong here ?

```
def last_activity(date, user_id)
  active_id = UserActivity.find(:all, :conditions => ["Date(updated_at) <= ? and user_id = ?", date, user_id]).last.activity_id
  text = Activity.find(active_id).description
end
```

The Schema of the model `UserActivity` is as follows :
[image]

Please help me get this fixed. Thanks !!

Ruby version 1.8.7, Rails 2.1.2

Comment: Does that bug occur to you when there are no values to be shown? In which case `last.activity_id` might be irrelevant. Does the answer in here help you in any way? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966430/model-find1-gives-activerecord-error-when-id-1-does-not-exist

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have following models

```
class User
  has_many :user_actvities
  has_many :activities, :through => :user_actvities, 
    :order => "user_actvities.id"
end

class UserActivity
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :activity
end

class Actvity
  has_many :user_actvities
  has_many :users, :through => :user_actvities
end
```

To get the current user's last activity

```
current_user.activities.last
```

This relies on the fact that UserActivity object with the max id is the latest activity.

If you update the `UserActivity` after creation, you have to change the `order` clause of the association, i.e.

```
has_many :activities, :through => :user_actvities, 
  :order => "user_actvities.updated_at"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the query is not finding any match or some records might be having `null` values for activity_id column, following code should work

```
user_activity = UserActivity.find(
   :all, :conditions => ["DATE(updated_at) <= ? AND user_id = ? AND activity_id IS NOT NULL", date, user_id], 
   :order => "updated_at DESC", :limit => 1).first
text = Activity.find(user_activity.active_id).description rescue nil
```

Comment: UserActivity and Activity are two different models completely... UserActivity keeps track of all user activities and in the function when I give a date and a user id I want that to fetch the most recent activity of the user within the date and from that activity_id I go to the activity model to fecth its description !