# find() with nil when there are no records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my current rails program when I use something like

```
 user = User.find(10)
```

When there is no user with ID=10 , I will have exception like :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with ID=10
```

Can I get nil instead of raising exception so when I do something like :

```
unless user = Challenge.find(10)
  puts "some error msg"         
end
```

I just want to get nil when there is no records and I don't want to use begin/rescue

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Model.find(1) gives ActiveRecord error when id 1 does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966430/model-find1-gives-activerecord-error-when-id-1-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Yes, just do:

```
Challenge.find_by_id(10)
```

For Rails 4 and 5:

```
Challenge.find_by(id: 10)
```

Comment: odd! I would've never guessed that the `.find_by_*` would return nil and the `.find` wouldn't.

Comment: This has changed in rails 4, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26885027/1438478 for the new way to find an item by a specific attribute.

Comment: I found a weird issue with Rails 4.2 where when you pass a hash as 'x'  to  `Something.find_by(id: x)` it would create a SQL statement with all the attribute/value pairs of the hash as part of the WHERE clause. Looks like a Rails bug to me.

Comment: Rails (3, 4 or 5) generates dynamic `find_by_...` finders for every attribute a model has including `:id`. So, `Challenge.find_by_id(10)` should work regardless of Rails version.

Comment: As specified by @MohamedIbrahim below, you can also do: `Challenge.find(10) rescue nil`

Answer (score 36):

In Rails 4, dynamic finders - such as `find_by_id` which was used in the accepted answer - were deprecated.

Moving forward, you should use the new syntax:

```
Challenge.find_by id: 10
```

Comment: In case anyone else is confused by this like me: `Challenge.find_by(id: 10)` is the other way of writing this

Answer (score 16):

you can do this a bit hackish, just use the ActiveRecord Query Interface.

this will return nil, instead of raising a Exception

```
  User.where(:id => 10).first
```

Comment: A reason to use this rather than `find_by_id` is that it's portable from Rails 3 to 4.  In rails 4, it's `find_by(:id => 10)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this `Challenge.exists?(10)`

Comment: it will be extra sql request

Comment: Even so I think this is better looking for testing

Comment: use it if you don't care about returned value but only about  the presence of a record in DB

Comment: As @fl00r mentioned, this might result in performance degradation, as in the case a record already exists, two trips to the database will be needed. Also, can you update the answer with the full code, to have a workable solution?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you simply catch the exception? Your case looks exactly like what exceptions were made for:

```
begin
  user = User.find(10)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  puts "some error msg"
end
```

If you want to recover from the error in the rescue block (e.g. by setting a placeholder user (null pattern)), you can continue with your code below this block. Otherwise you might just put all your code for the "happy case" in the block between "begin" and "rescue".

Comment: Btw: you don't even need the `begin…end` block, if you already have a block such as a controller method. In that case the only extra line you need is the `rescue` line. Much more elegant and easier to handle than checking for `nil` with an `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

For those struggling with **mongoid**, it turns out that both `find` and `find_by` methods will raise exception - no matter your rails version!

There is an [option](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-installation/) (namely *raise_not_found_error*) which can be set to false, but when falsey makes `find` method doesn't to raise exception as well.

Thus the solution for mongoid users is the disgusting code:

```
User.where(id: 'your_id').first # argghhh
```

Comment: What do you think of the rescue nil solution by mohamed-ibrahim? Seems more elegant than `.where(email: params[:email]).first` to me.

Comment: I rather not to use that `rescue` syntax since it can hide problems such as typos

Comment: I wound up using @morgler's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find_by with the required attribute (in your case the id) this will return nil instead of giving an error if the given id is not found.

```
user = Challenge.find_by_id(id_value)
```

or you could use the new format:

```
user = Challenge.find_by id: id_value
```

You could also use where but you have to know that where return an active record relation with zero or more records you need to use first to return only one record or nil in case zero records return.

```
user = Challenge.where(id: id_value).first
```

Comment: Basically this is repeating solutions already provided by previous answers.

Answer (score -1):

just as simple as:

```
user = User.find(10) rescue nil
```

Comment: I would rather be more specific about what error is expected to be rescued, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in this case. As pointed on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35115377/2112183) by @morgler

Comment: I personally find this to be the best answer. I'm already telling my code what to do if the user isn't found in `if user...else`

Comment: This is bad practice, as this will swallow all exceptions, not only the "not found one", making your code less reliable.