# Active Record `find` returns nil when a valid record exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm running the following tests for my `ArticlesController`.

```html
  describe "#destroy" do
    let(:article) { articles(:article_1) }
    let(:request) { delete :destroy, params: { id: article.id.to_s } }

    it 'returns a 200 status socde when a correct request is made' do
      request
      expect(request.status).to eq 302
    end

    it 'deletes an article' do
      expect{ request }.to change{ Article.count }.by(-1)
    end

    it 'deletes the correct article' do
      expect(Article).to receive(:find).with(article.id.to_s)
      request
    end
  end
```

This is my current destroy action in `ArticlesController`:

```html
def destroy
    p "********"
    p params[:id].to_i
    p Article.find_by(id: params[:id])
    p Article.find(params[:id])
    article.destroy
    redirect_to articles_path
  end

 def article
  @article ||= Article.find(params[:id])
 end
```

which outputs ( for the final test only, the first two pass):

```html
 "********"
960213061
#<Article id: 960213061, title: "First Article", body: "This is the first test article", published_at: nil, created_at: "2016-12-19 09:11:55", updated_at: "2016-12-19 09:11:55">
nil
F
```

So `find_by(id: params[:id]` finds the records fine, but `find(params[:id])` only returns nil. Also `find(params[:id].to_i)` returns nil. Can anyone spot why? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**Updated**

The destroy method itself works as expected in development. It's just the test thats failing with:

```html
 1) ArticlesController#destroy deletes the correct article
     Failure/Error: article.destroy

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:30:in `destroy'
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:101:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: What is `article` in `ArticlesController`? Seems like undefined to me.

Comment: @AlexanderMorozov: Updated the question. Sorry forgot to add that `article` is a method in my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer. The problem was with the link in my test: `expect(Article).to receive(:find).with(article.id.to_s)`. Without stating what I want `Article.find(params[:id)` to return, it returns `nil`. Hence no error message was received and `find_by(id: params[:id]) worked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `find` raise `RecordNotFound` exception when can't find the record so it can't simply puts `nil` and continue executing your function, make sure you are not override your find function in `Article` model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a fairly new project so atm my Article Model is empty. Did find it odd that nil was returned and not an error.

Comment: yes, sure that is why there is `find` and `find_by_id` or yours `find_by(id: value)` as `find` always raise an exception when no result returned.
check also http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find
and check this answer also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604585/find-with-nil-when-there-are-no-records