# Rails ActiveRecord [find] method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails document,I find that:

```
Person.find(1, 2, 6) # returns an array for objects with IDs in (1, 2, 6)
```

But when I execute this command,I got

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Persons with IDs (1, 2, 6) 
(found 1 results, but was looking for 2)
```

How I got this error? My Rails version is `3.2.14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error points out that there are no records in `Person` with the `id`s `1`, `2` and `6`.

The syntax `Person.find([1,2,6])` and `Person.find(1, 2, 6)` is equivalent and correct to retrieve multiple records by id. Please have a look [into](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) the API documentation.

Maybe you check what is into the table. Start a `irb`-shell of your project and print all records of `Person` by writing: `Person.all`

I cannot find `find_all_by` in the newest API documentation and the argumentation is wrong that `find` raises a `RecordNotFound` exception. It raises an `RecordNotFound` if none of the id's were found. The documentation says to [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find):

> If no record can be found for all of the listed ids, then RecordNotFound will be raised.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831347/rails-why-does-findid-raise-an-exception-in-rails).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct syntax for pulling multiple id's at once is `Person.find([1,2,6])`. If this still returns `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` then the records with those id's don't exist.

In order to get around the error for if an id does not exist, you can do `Person.find_all_by_id([1,2,6])`. In this case, if it doesn't find records it should return an empty array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure that records exist with those id numbers?

Answer (score 1):

`find` expects to find all records, if one is missing you will get `RecordNotFound`

If you want it to work without erroring when ids are missing use

```
Person.where("id in (1,2,6)")
```